# Error during the second SSL certificate request for a site hosted on a VPS with webmin

Tags: ssl-certificate, webmin

I encounter this error which I put in brackets. I want to install the SSL certificate on my site which is hosted on a vps with webmin, when I did it the first time it worked my site had the SSL certificate with let's Encrypt but afterwards I wanted to start all over again so I deleted the server and all the files from my site then I created a new server with the same name as the old server but now when I try to request the ssl certificate at the level of my webmin it no longer works while the first time it worked well, I put the error that is displayed in parentheses ( Requesting a certificate for ertiden from Let's Encrypt ..

> Request failed : Web-based validation failed :
> Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
> Plugins selected: Authenticator webroot, Installer None
> Obtaining a new certificate
> An unexpected error occurred:
> Error creating new order :: Cannot issue for "ertiden": Domain name needs at least one dot
> Please see the logfiles in /var/log/letsencrypt for more details.
> DNS-based validation failed : Neither DNS zone or any of its sub-domains exist on this system )

Comment: what is your domain name? this error says your domain name not is real domain name.

Comment: _"Domain name needs at least one dot"_ - Seems like the domain name is invalid. Don't you have a TLD, like `.com`, `.net` or similar?

Comment: @TayfunYuksel yes my friend you are right, I had not added the .com extension to my domain name. when I added the .com extension it worked but I haven't finished yet because I have to go to the Service certificates but Service certificates does not appear in my SSL Certificate tab

Comment: This issue doesn't seem to be related to PHP or htaccess and definitely not MySQL though. You should only add tags that are relevant to the issue at hand.

Comment: @M.Eriksson I found where it says Service Certificates it was hidden at the bottom, at the bottom. Now everything works, my site has the SSL certificate. Thank you my friends!

Comment: @Tayfun Yuksel I found where it says Service Certificates it was hidden at the bottom, at the bottom. Now everything works, my site has the SSL certificate. Thank you my friends!

Comment: @KDVB You're wellcome have a nice day